# Getter in a Behavior cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, behavior, cakephp-3.x

I've just created a tag behavior to manage tags in an input text field (all keywords are separate by a comma). To do that I name my input "tag_string".
So I need to use a getter to handle the string.
I didn't understand how implement a _getTagString() method directly in the behavior.

If I use my getter (getTagString) in each entities file that use my behavior all my code works fine.
So to avoid write the same getter in each file I want to put it in my behavior file. But it doesn't work.

Here is my method:

```
public function _getTagString() {
    if (isset($this->_properties['tag_string'])) {
        return $this->_properties['tag_string'];
    }
    if (empty($entity->tags)) {
        return '';
    }
    $tags = new Collection($entity->tags);
    $str = $tags->reduce(function ($string, $tag) {
        return $string . $tag->name . ', ';
    }, '');
    return trim($str, ', ');
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what `_getTagString()` does exactly, and how you plan to use its return value. Without knowing that, people will have a hard time telling you anything else than the fact that accessors are for entities only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

After several searches I didn't find anything to implement accessors directly in the behavior.

I use trait, and It works fine.